# Remove group of rows by flag indicator in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I have groups of numbers in the unique3 column.

```
structure(list(unique1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("11/1/2016", "11/10/2016", "11/11/2016", 
                                                            "11/12/2016", "11/13/2016", "11/14/2016", "11/15/2016", "11/16/2016", 
                                                            "11/17/2016", "11/18/2016", "11/19/2016", "11/2/2016", "11/20/2016", 
                                                            "11/21/2016", "11/22/2016", "11/23/2016", "11/24/2016", "11/25/2016", 
                                                            "11/26/2016", "11/27/2016", "11/28/2016", "11/3/2016", "11/4/2016", 
                                                            "11/5/2016", "11/6/2016", "11/7/2016", "11/8/2016", "11/9/2016"
                                    ), 
                        class = "factor"), unique2 = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
                          21L, 21L, 31L, 41L), unique3 = c(100001L, 100001L, 100001L, 100001L, 
                                                       100001L, 100001L, 100001L, 100001L, 100002L, 100003L), 
               flag = c(NA_integer_,1, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                           NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), value = c(1L, 
                                                                                      6L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 1L, 1L)), 
          .Names = c("unique1","unique2", "unique3", "flag", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

     unique1 unique2 unique3 flag value
1  11/1/2016      21  100001   NA     1
2  11/1/2016      21  100001    1     6
3  11/1/2016      21  100001   NA    18
4  11/1/2016      21  100001   NA    19
5  11/1/2016      21  100001   NA    22
6  11/1/2016      21  100001   NA    29
7  11/1/2016      21  100001   NA    30
8  11/1/2016      21  100001   NA    32
9  11/1/2016      31  100002   NA     1
10 11/1/2016      41  100003   NA     1
```

I basically need to group by unique column 3 where if any of the rows for 100001 had a 1 in flag. They would be removed. Although 100001 may not be unique and may repeat for a different value of unique2.

What I would do is make all the values for unique 3  to have a value of 1 like so

```
     unique1 unique2 unique3 flag value
1  11/1/2016      21  100001   1     1
2  11/1/2016      21  100001   1     6
3  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    18
4  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    19
5  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    22
6  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    29
7  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    30
8  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    32
9  11/1/2016      31  100002   NA     1
10 11/1/2016      41  100003   NA     1
```

and then group by and filter to have:

```
 unique1 unique2 unique3 flag value
1  11/1/2016      21  100001   1     1
2  11/1/2016      21  100001   1     6
3  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    18
4  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    19
5  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    22
6  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    29
7  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    30
8  11/1/2016      21  100001   1    32
```

Comment: @Frank yes that would be fine

Comment: Are you trying to keep, or remove the groups that have a flag of 1? Your question includes "They would be removed" but your sample output appears to keep them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first step (applying the flag uniformly to each group):

```
DF$flag <- ave(DF$flag, DF$unique3, FUN = function(x) max(c(0,x), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Then you can filter a few different ways. One option is:

```
subset(DF, flag == 1)
```

---

*How it works*

`ave(v, g1, g2, g3, FUN = f)` splits up vector `v` based on grouping variables; applies a function to each subvector; recombines to return a vector with the same class as `v`.

`max(c(0,x), na.rm=TRUE)` removes the NA values, adds a 0 value and then takes the max. If `x` only contains 1s and NAs, this will return a 1 if `x` contains any 1 and otherwise returns 0.

---

*Some alternatives with packages*

```
library(data.table)
DT = setDT(copy(DF))

DT[, flag := max(c(0,flag), na.rm=TRUE), by=unique3][ flag == 1 ] 

# or...
library(dplyr)
DF2 = DF

(DF2 %<>% 
  group_by(unique3) %>% 
  mutate(flag = max(c(0,flag), na.rm=TRUE))
) %>% filter(flag == 1)
```

(I'm only creating the DF2 and DT objects here so the code can be run directly without conflicting edits on DF.)

Comment: A general doubt related about data.table.  In the current edition 1.10.0, if we are doing operations on each column with `lapply` or `for`, does it make use of the parallelism implicitly?

Comment: @akrun I'm not sure. I think I've seen some convos in the issue tracker about work on parallelization but I haven't really followed them. You could review there and then ask someone more knowledgeable. The support guidance on the tracker used to describe how to ask a question there (putting "[Question]" in the title), but I don't see that any more https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support so maybe best to ask in chat, probably GMTs. My guess is that there is not parallelization across columns but might be across groups/subsets.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with just `dplyr`. Here, I `group_by`, then use `any` to return whether or not any values in that column are "1". If you have more complicated criteria in your use case, you could include them here.

```
df %>%
  group_by(unique3) %>%
  mutate(newFlag = any(flag == 1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

returns:

```
     unique1 unique2 unique3  flag value newFlag
      <fctr>   <int>   <int> <dbl> <int>   <lgl>
1  11/1/2016      21  100001    NA     1    TRUE
2  11/1/2016      21  100001     1     6    TRUE
3  11/1/2016      21  100001    NA    18    TRUE
4  11/1/2016      21  100001    NA    19    TRUE
5  11/1/2016      21  100001    NA    22    TRUE
6  11/1/2016      21  100001    NA    29    TRUE
7  11/1/2016      21  100001    NA    30    TRUE
8  11/1/2016      21  100001    NA    32    TRUE
9  11/1/2016      31  100002    NA     1   FALSE
10 11/1/2016      41  100003    NA     1   FALSE
```

where the column `newFlag` accomplishes what I think you are requesting. You can overwrite `flag` instead if you prefer.

You can use it to filter as such:

```
df %>%
  group_by(unique3) %>%
  mutate(newFlag = any(flag == 1, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(newFlag)
```

From your question, it is unclear whether you want to keep or discard groups that have a flag. If you want to remove them, use `filter(!newFlag)` instead. In either case, if you want to be rid of the new column after filtering, use `select(-newFlag)`.

Comment: Yeah, I think `any` is better than my approach (with `max`). Fyi, OP asked two questions, second being how to filter to where newFlag is true.

Comment: Thank you @Frank, and you are right about the filtering. I added a filtering step now, though I had omitted it before because the question contained conflicting information on whether they were to be kept or discarded.